# how do i use the a tag to direct to a picture in an image slide on another page

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am trying to point an anchor tag to the third image on my slider on another page , but it keeps taking me to the first image on the slider , how can i resolve this and get my third image in the slider to show when a tag is clicked.

this is my anchor tag code

```
  <a href="speakerid.php#s2"><h5 class="in-view__child in-view__child--fadein">Georgia Arnold</h5></a>
```

this is my slider code for the third image

```
<li id="s2">

<div class="board board--left">

<div class="row align-items-end">

<div class="col-12 col-md-6">

<div class="board__image poster in-view">

<figure><img class="lazyload--el lazyload in-view__child" src="assets/media/georgia.png" data-src="assets/media/georgia.png" alt="" width="445" height="600">

<div class="poster--cover in-view in-view__child" data-offset="90%"></div>

</figure>

</div>

</div>

<div class="col-12 col-md-6">

<div class="board__copy in-view">

<h2 class="in-view__child in-view__child--fadein">Georgia <br>Arnold</h2>

<p class="sub-head dashed in-view__child in-view__child--fadein">test <br>work</p>

<p class="indent in-view__child in-view__child--fadein">this is a test paragraph</p>

<p class="board__copy--links indent in-view__child in-view__child--fadein"><span class="sub-head dashed dashed--reverse dashed--hover in-view__child"><a href="#"><span class="sr-only">Follow us on linkedin</span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin-square"></i></a><a href="#"><span class="sr-only">Follow us on facebook</span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook-square"></i></a><a href="#"><span class="sr-only">Follow us on twitter</span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter-square"></i></a></span></p>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</li>
```

this is my javascript code

```
var script = new function (){
var slider;

var sliderInit = function(){

slider = $("ul#hSlider").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,

  responsive: {
    0:{
      items: 1
    },
    992:{
      items: 1
    }
  }
});

sliderNavigation();
};


var sliderNavigation = function(){

var navItem = $(".slide a");

navItem.click(function(event){
  if($(this).hasClass("next")){
    slider.trigger("next.owl.carousel");
  }
  else{
    slider.trigger("prev.owl.carousel");
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  });
  snRepositioning();

  $(window).resize(function(){

  snRepositioning();
});
};

var snRepositioning = function(){

var sliderHeight = $("ul#hSlider").outerHeight();

var navHeight = $(".slide a").outerHeight();

var newHeight = (sliderHeight - navHeight) / 2;

$(".slide").css({top: newHeight+"px"}); 
};

this.init = function(){
sliderInit();
};
};

$(function(){
  script.init();
});
```

Comment: SO isn't a free coding website. Show us what've you tried so far.

Comment: Hello, you should provide the code you used, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: i did , i just edited my code now so you'll be able to see it

Comment: Thanks for the code, you could have indented it though... Is that li element a part of your slider ? You should give us the whole code then (don't hesitate to remove useless parts (like non relevant text and paragraphs) so that we have a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: More context and more code (javascript ?) wouldn't hurt either (how the slider is made, etc).